# Regexp for extracting a mailto: address

Tags: php, regex, string, text-extraction

I'd like a reg exp which can take a block of string, and find the strings matching the format:

```
<a href="mailto:x@x.com">....</a>
```

And for all strings which match this format, it will extract out the email address found after the `mailto:`. Any thoughts?

This is needed for an internal app and not for any spammer purposes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match the whole thing from :

```
$r = '`\<a([^>]+)href\=\"mailto\:([^">]+)\"([^>]*)\>(.*?)\<\/a\>`ism';
preg_match_all($r,$html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

To fastern and shortern it:

```
$r = '`\<a([^>]+)href\=\"mailto\:([^">]+)\"([^>]*)\>`ism';
preg_match_all($r,$html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The 2nd matching group will be whatever email it is.

Example:

```
$html ='<div><a href="mailto:test@live.com">test</a></div>';

$r = '`\<a([^>]+)href\=\"mailto\:([^">]+)\"([^>]*)\>(.*?)\<\/a\>`ism';
preg_match_all($r,$html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(39) "test"
    [1]=>
    string(1) " "
    [2]=>
    string(13) "test@live.com"
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
    [4]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of different options on [regexp.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

One example would be:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

The "`mailto:`" is trivial to prepend to that.

Comment: This regular expression only matches capital letters so make sure to use a case insensitivity flag with this one. Alternatively, consider adding lowercase letter to the regex.

Comment: can you prepend the mailto: as well as the case insensivity switch asaph has brought up? I'm not familiar with regexp syntax so i can't fix it myself even if its trivial

Answer (score 0):

```
/(mailto:)(.+)(\")/
```

The second matching group will be the email address.

Comment: which function should i use with this, preg_match?

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the internal PHP filter https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

(they have one which is specially there for validating or sanitizing email -> FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)

Greets

Comment: How would that allow the email to be extracted out?

Answer (score 0):

for me worked `~<mailto(.*?)>~`
will return an array containing elements found.
Here you can test it: https://regex101.com/r/rTmKR4/1