# Php crawl to fetch emails pattern

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regexp for extracting a mailto: address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376149/regexp-for-extracting-a-mailto-address)

I want to fetch the emails withing a page through the following scrip, but i am not sure about the pattern to use in preg_match_all.

```
 $original_file = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/");
 $stripped_file = strip_tags($original_file, "<a>");
 preg_match_all("/<a(?:[^>]*)href=\"([^\"]*)\"(?:[^>]*)>(?:[^<]*)<\/a>/is", $stripped_file, $matches);

 header("Content-type: text/plain"); 
 print_r($matches); //View the array to see if it worked
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have more luck using an HTML parser such as [PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) which will let you parse the HTML document in a more natural way such as:

```
// Find all anchors, returns a array of element objects
$ret = $html->find('a');
```

Then loop through the array of returned elements and check the `href` for something like the @ symbol.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I've just realised you meant mailto: links**

Answer here:

[Regexp for extracting a mailto: address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376149/regexp-for-extracting-a-mailto-address)

Comment: The second argument to strip_tags() sets which tags to preserve.