# How can I use regex to strip the email address from a mailto tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to parse the email address from a `mailto` tag. I am looking for a way to do this via RegEx in C#.

#### Example input:

```
<mailto:abc@xyz.com>
```

#### Example output:

```
abc@xyz.com
```

Comment: Why regex? Wouldn't `.Substring()` be sufficient here?

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376149/regexp-for-extracting-a-mailto-address

Comment: b'coz i have long html string. and in html lots of this kind of tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, [it's a very bad idea to use regular expressions for HTML parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/674700). Instead, take a look at the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). For the specific input you provided, you may use:

`(?<=\<mailto:).*(?=\>)`

Here's a code sample:

```
var emailTag = "<mailto:abc@xyz.com>";
var emailValue = Regex.Match(emailTag, @"(?<=\<mailto:).*(?=\>)").Value;
Console.WriteLine(emailValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple Regex to strip anything in a mailto tag would be

```
<mailto:(.*?)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
[\w\d]+\@[\w\d]+\.com
```

`[\w\d]`   <----This matches any letter or character. `\w` matches any letter. `\d` matches anynumber.

`+`   <----One or more of previous item, in this case `[\w\d]+` one or more letters or numbers

`\@`   <----Simply matches the @ symbol but it needs to be escaped with a `\` as it is a special character

`[\w\d]+`    <----Same again

`\.`     <---- Same concept as the @ as `.` is a special character so it needs to be escaped

In your example:
`[\w\d]+`=abc
`\@`=@
`[\w\d]+`=xyz
`\.`=.
`com`=com

If your wanting to match special characters as well as letters and digits then just replace `[\w\d]+` with `[\S]+` (make sure s is capital).

`[\S]+` <---Matches anything that is not a space.

You will have to do variations to include .co.uk and .org etc.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html <----This is very useful!

Comment: Sorry you will need a look behind also, so prefix this regex with (?<=\<mailto:)