# callback on each regex match in string

Tags: javascript, php, regex, wordpress

In wordpress but in php more generally, following this [suggestion](https://perishablepress.com/best-method-for-email-obfuscation/), I would like to

1. convert email addresses to mailto links and
2. encode mailto links with str_13()
3. to be decoded client side by javascript.

I'm doing fine on the 1st count

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'make_clickable',      12 );
```

and I don't yet know whether on the 3rd count this will work

```
document.write("<n uers=\"znvygb:xvpx@vaprcgvba.pbz\" ery=\"absbyybj\">Fraq n zrffntr</n>".replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, 
function(c){return String.fromCharCode((c<="Z"?90:122)>=(c=c.charCodeAt(0)+13)?c:c-26);}));
```

I think what I want to do is in  or instead of the preg_replace inject str_13() on every occurrence just after it gets replaced. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082207/calling-function-inside-preg-replace-thats-inside-a-function) and tried to transfer the answer to my case:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'email_encoder', 99);

function email_encoder($content) {
    return preg_replace_callback('`\<a([^>])href\=\"mailto\:([^">])\"([^>]*)\>`ism', 'encode_str_13', $content);
}

function encode_str_13($matches)
{
     return str_13($matches[1]);      
}
```

which changes nothing and I'm at a loss, why. I suspect it's the regex I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376149/regexp-for-extracting-a-mailto-address) or array item address, if I change it somewhat, literally nothing get's displayed anymore until I revert the change (I don't seem to be right about what I think I'm doing).

can you please help me encode all mailto links and correct my javascript to decode them again?

Thanks

EDIT: this is an example $content:

```
<p>text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
numbers<br>
<a href="mailto:....>...</a><br>
<a href="...." rel="nofollow">....</a></p>
```

and indeed I did mean str_rot13() instead of str_13()

EDIT2:

The JS I went with after more fiddling is this:

```
var collection = jQuery(".encoded");
collection.each(function() {

var encoded = jQuery( this ).html();

var decoded = encoded.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function(c){return String.fromCharCode((c<="Z"?90:122)>=(c=c.charCodeAt(0)+13)?c:c-26);});
jQuery(this).html(decoded);
jQuery(this).prop('class', 'decoded')

});
```

Comment: Can you provide sample `$content`? I'm also not familiar with `str_13`, what does that do? Maybe it should be http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php?

Comment: ah! you're right, that would have bitten me had I gotten the regex right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is a bit wrong, here is a correct one([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/6JyZDg/1)):

```
`\<a([^>])href\=\"mailto\:([^">]+)\"([^>]*)\>`ism
```

And in your callback use `2` index, like:

```
function encode_str_13($matches)
{
     return str_13($matches[2]);      
}
```

Comment: thank you, that was marvellously quick and concise. Was I really just missing the + sign in the second group?! and thanks for rectifying that array.

Comment: a closing remark: your regex and array address correctly encode the emailadress. I went one step further: `return preg_replace_callback('/\<a([^>]+)href\=\"mailto\:([^>]+)\"([^>]*)\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/is', 'encode_str_13', $content);` and `return "<span class='encoded'>".str_rot13($matches[0])."</span>";` encoding the entire `<a .../a>` to be decoded and reclassed as decoded in JS (see my post)